# Vaadin Flow: Grid Select All is ignoring Filtering

Tags: filter, checkbox, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

#### Vaadin Framework Version:

23.1.7

#### Issue

I'm building up a web application using Vaadin. In the view I added a Grid and set

```
grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.MULTI);
```

I also added a FilterField, that filters the GridListDataView.

The Multiselect and the filter working fine, each for it's own. But when I try to Filter the grid, then click the "Select All" Checkbox in the header column all rows in the grid are selected (also those, which are currently not visible, because of the filter.

In fact, it's exactly the issue mentioned here: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/10595 , which should have been fixed by vaadin 8.9.0, but I'm still/again facing this issue.

#### Question

Is there any known way to work around that and get only those items selected that are currently visible?

Comment: Known issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/3614

Comment: Much of Vaadin was rewritten between version 8 and 10, so issues related to version 8 in the `framework` repository might not have any relationship to issues related to newer versions in e.g. the `flow` or `flow-components` repositories.

Comment: Suggested a workaround https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/3614#issuecomment-1256150701